# AppWidget: Updating ImageView with drawables?

Tags: android, drawable, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create an appwidget with a customizable background. I use a NinePatchDrawable and I would like to change it's color (using the setColorFilter method). This is no problem in an Activity, but it does dot seem possible with the RemoteView object used for appwidgets.

Is there some way to get an ImageView in an appwidget to be updated with a new Drawable, not a Bitmap?

Or if not, perhaps it's possible to get the actual size of the appwidget and convert / save the colored NinePatchDrawable to a Bitmap and then update the ImageView with that?

I already searched quite a bit for a solution, but haven't found anything so far. I hope it's not impossible.
Thanks,

Froghut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to get an ImageView in an appwidget to be updated with a new Drawable, not a Bitmap?

`setImageViewResource()` does not imply a bitmap, but it does have to be a resource.

> perhaps it's possible to get the actual size of the appwidget

No, sorry.

> I hope it's not impossible.

Don't allow an infinite range of colors. Allow customization for a handful of colors for which you include appropriate resources.

Comment: Well, seems I will have to take your advice and only allow a predefined range of colors. Thanks

Comment: `perhaps it's possible to get the actual size of the appwidget` : It's possible. Tell me if anyone needs the code

Comment: @mnVoh: "It's possible" -- in November 2010 (when the answer was written), you could not get any information about app widget size. Now you can get size ranges, but not the exact size.

Comment: I didn't know that. But the reason I said that is because, no matter how old a question is, sometimes people see it, and if there's new information on it, it would help them a lot. Thanks for the response anyways :-) But to be fair, I should've provided the code, not tell me if you needed it.

Comment: @mnVoh: In particular, if you have sample code that demonstrates generating a custom bitmap based upon those size ranges, that would make for a useful additional answer on this question. The trick there is not blowing out the `RemoteViews` size limit.

Comment: I deleted my answer. You were right. Even if it works it requires a much higher API, i suppose.